# What's a generic word for both Methods and Attributes?

Tags: object-oriented, wording

In a class diagram, each class contains methods and attributes. What's the correct word for describing both of them besides something generic such as contents or items?

Context:

> The Orange class extends the Fruit class and inherits its **stuff**.

where *stuff* = a single word for both methods and attributes

Comment: "Properties" might also be reasonable, but that is often used for specific kinds of members.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "members". Typically they are referred to as "class members".

> The Orange class extends the Fruit class and inherits its *members*.

Comment: That's it! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Holy popular batman! This is my new high score of an answer, and I didn't even spend 30 seconds writing it out.

Comment: @zzzzBov You were tweeted by StackProgrammer https://twitter.com/#!/StackProgrammer/status/121797550570352640

Comment: @zzzzBov good for u :0

Comment: Further point, the terms "static members" and "instance members" can refer to both methods or attributes. I've heard the term "member variables" used a fair bit as well.

Comment: @dodgy_coder: Yep "member variable" is often abbreviated to member. Which is fine... I guess.